# Bash: How to assign the value of an environment variable to a local variable?

Tags: bash

I'm sure that I'm missing something basic but I can't figure it out. This is a simple test/learning script to assign the value of one variable BITBUCKET_TAG to the local variable varr. In this case, I've defined BITBUCKET_TAG explicitly, but ultimately it will be an environment variable. Here is a sequence of various command syntax attempts that I've tried (based on a bunch of SO and other internet searches) along with the return values (if any).

```
BITBUCKET_TAG=2.2.2

$ if [[ $BITBUxCKET_TAG ]]; then varr=$BITBUCKET_TAG; else varr="Nothing to see here"; echo $varr; fi
Nothing to see here

$ if [[ $BITBUCKET_TAG ]]; then varr="$BITBUCKET_TAG"; else varr="Nothing to see here"; echo $varr; fi

$ if [[ $BITBUCKET_TAG ]]; then varr="${BITBUCKET_TAG}"; else varr="Nothing to see here"; echo $varr; fi

$ if [[ $BITBUCKET_TAG ]]; then varr="$!BITBUCKET_TAG"; else varr="Nothing to see here"; echo $varr; fi

$ if [[ $BITBUCKET_TAG ]]; then varr="${!BITBUCKET_TAG}"; else varr="Nothing to see here"; echo $varr; fi
bash: 2.2.2: bad substitution

$ if [[ $BITBUCKET_TAG ]]; then varr=${!BITBUCKET_TAG}; else varr="Nothing to see here"; echo $varr; fi
bash: 2.2.2: bad substitution
```

Obviously, the last two are the closest to working the way that I want, but I don't know what is causing the bad substitution error. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why `BITBUxCKET_TAG` instead of `BITBUCKET_TAG` ??

Comment: The last two attempts utilize `varr=${!BITBUCKET_TAG}`.  Seems like there may be a stray `!` in the variable name.

Comment: Why not simply doing a `varr=$BITBUCKET_TAG`, or (if you run with `set -u`) `varr=${BITBUCKET_TAG:-}`ß

Comment: As for the bad substitution: `${!BITBUCKET_TAG}` takes the content of the variable `BITBUCKET_TAG` as the name of another variable, and tries to fetch the value of the latter. In your case, the value is `2.2.2`, so you basically ask bash to get the value of a variable with the name _2.2.2_.

Comment: Do you **really** need two distinct variables here? Otherwise, a `: ${BITBUCKET_TAG:=default}` would do (where _default_ is the value you want to store when _BITBUCKET_TAG_ does not exist or is empty.

Comment: @user1934428 The statement is part of a larger build pipeline. The reason why I need two variables is because BITBUCKET_TAG is an environment variable that is set by our build pipeline, but I want to guarantee that it is not an empty string for a grep statement later in the pipeline (not shown here). When it's an empty string, the grep would pass but I want it to fail, so I replace it with a random string. I guess that I could have overwritten the env variable when it was empty, but I preferred to not mess with it.

Comment: @GillesQuénot I added an 'x' to the first line just to make sure that the ELSE was working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
 if [[ $BITBUCKET_TAG ]]; then 
   varr="$BITBUCKET_TAG"
 else 
   varr="Nothing to see here"
 fi 
 echo "$varr"
```

Note that I've moved your `echo` to outside of the `else` block.

(I've converted your one liner to something that is legible even in mobile views. The `;` are correct for one liners).

You're misusing the "dereference" operator (${!var}).
Note what you get if you just execute

```
echo "${!BITBUCKET_TAG}"
bash: 2.2.2: invalid variable name
```

`${!BITBUCKET_TAG}` is expecting another variable name and `2.2.2` can't be used as a variable name AND there is no value assigned to it.

Learn to use `set -x` to see how your code is executing. The line preceded `+` is showing your code with all env-var, parameter expansions complete.

Learn to check you code at https://shellcheck.net and fix any issues flagged before posting code here. Include a note like "Shellcheck validated"

# --------- just FYI --------------

Vars with strings including spaces will be "normalized" with single quotes, that is

```
X="2. 2.2"
+ X='2 2.2'
echo "$X"
+ echo '2 2.2'
2 2.2
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew that it was something simple (dooooh!).

Answer (score 4):

When you copying data from some variable to another variable and there is a chance that there is no data to copy. And you need to workaround this somehow by adding some default value for example. There is special bash syntax for this:

```
var=${BITBUCKET_TAG:-Nothing to see here}
$ echo $var
Nothing to see here

BITBUCKET_TAG=2.2.2
var=${BITBUCKET_TAG:-Nothing to see here}
$ echo $var
2.2.2
```

Comment: (reposted after minor edit) : Good stuff! But one quibble, In regards to the `:-Nothing..}`, I think "assign" is too strong a word. There is also a syntax of `var=${BITBUCKET_TAG:=Nothing to see here}` which will truly assign that "default" value to the variable. In the case for the O.P. the assignment still happens to `$var`, but `$BITBUCKET_TAG` by itself is still has no value. Look at what happens with just a bare variable, `unset z; echo X${z:-tempDefault}X ; echo X${z}X; echo ${z:=permanentDefault} ; echo X${z}X` ; Good luck to all.

Comment: Assign to `$var` variable.

Comment: I've tried to explain with more details.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't familiar with this notation. It's cleaner than my if/else statement too.